# How to config entry Dart file for Make Project function in Android

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am trying to build a Flutter project, but it shows this error message. Now I want to config  the entry point.

```
> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDevelopmentDebug
lib/main.dart: Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In the project, I have three entry points for three build types: Development, Staging, Production. This style is generated by `very_good` package, which is a package for fastening the creating package process.

Here is my project structure.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you provided, it seems that the Flutter build process is unable to find the `lib/main.dart` file. This could be due to a misconfiguration in your project setup or a problem with the build process.

Since you mentioned that you have three entry points for three build types (Development, Staging, Production) generated by the `very_good` package, let's investigate further and try to resolve the issue:

1. Check the file structure:
   Ensure that the `lib/main.dart` file exists in your project and is in the correct location. Open your project directory in your file explorer and navigate to `lib/main.dart`. Verify that the file is present and contains the necessary Flutter app setup.
2. Verify Flutter SDK installation:
   Ensure that you have installed Flutter and Dart SDKs correctly on your machine. You can check your Flutter installation by running the following command in your terminal or command prompt:

   ```
   flutter doctor
   ```

   This command will display information about your Flutter installation and whether there are any issues.
3. Check build configurations:
   If you are using different entry points for different build types (Development, Staging, Production), you need to make sure that your `very_good_analysis_options.yaml` file (or similar configuration file) is set up correctly to point to the appropriate entry points for each build type.
4. Verify `very_good_analysis_options.yaml`:
   Check the content of your `very_good_analysis_options.yaml` file and verify that the paths to the entry points are correctly specified for each build type.
5. Clean and rebuild:
   Sometimes, build issues can be resolved by cleaning the build artifacts and then rebuilding the project. In Android Studio, you can try selecting "Build" from the top menu and then "Clean Project" or "Rebuild Project."
6. Check Flutter version and dependencies:
   Ensure that you are using a compatible version of Flutter and the `very_good` package. Check for any updates or compatibility issues between your Flutter version, the `very_good` package, and other dependencies.
7. Update the Flutter and Dart plugins in Android Studio:
   Make sure you have the latest versions of the Flutter and Dart plugins installed in Android Studio. Go to "Preferences" (macOS) or "Settings" (Windows), then "Plugins," and search for "Flutter" and "Dart" plugins to check for updates.
8. Restart Android Studio and Flutter:
   Sometimes, restarting Android Studio and the Flutter daemon can resolve various build issues. Close Android Studio, stop any running Flutter processes, and then start Android Studio and your Flutter project again.

If you've followed these steps and the issue persists, it might be helpful to provide more context or the content of your `very_good_analysis_options.yaml` file to identify any potential configuration issues. Additionally, checking the Flutter and Dart plugin versions can be beneficial, as well as verifying the overall project structure and file locations.

Comment: `very_good_analysis_options.yaml`. I'll read more about this file.